# D3 v5 Post using fetch returning Unhandled promise rejection 405

Tags: javascript, d3.js, fetch

I'm trying to use D3 fetch to post values to my servlet, following this link: https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/posting-with-fetch.
Is anybody able to advise what is going wrong here? - thanks in advance.

My D3 Fetch statement is as follows:

```
d3.select('#myButton').on('click', function(){

d3.json("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/SomeServlet", {
body: JSON.stringify({"valuetosubmit": "test"}),
headers: {"content-type": "application/json"},
method: "POST",
mode: "cors"
})
});
```

Extract from my dummy servlet that isn't being reached below:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse      response) throws ServletException, IOException {
           Map<String, String> options = new LinkedHashMap<>();
           String searchno=request.getParameter("searchedPart");
           System.out.println(searchno);
           options.put("value1", "label1");
           options.put("value2", "label2");
           options.put("value3", "label3");
           String data = new Gson().toJson(options);

           System.out.println(data);
           response.setContentType("application/json");
           response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
           response.getWriter().write(data);
       }
```

Which is throwing the following error: Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: 405

Comment: There are two issues here: 1) Your server returns a ["405 Method Not Allowed"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405).  You are showing your `doGet()` method—are you sure you even implemented the POST action? 2) This error will cause an exception to be [thrown](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/src/json.js#L2) by D3 which causes the Promise returned by `d3.json()` to be rejected. This rejection, however, is not handled by your code as there is no `.catch()`. Since it is even missing a `.then()` the response will never be handled at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response. on point 2 It was to my understanding with D3-fetch a catch & then wasn't required as per Mikes comment in the above link?.post(
    //   JSON.stringify({searchedPart: "2012"}),
    //   function(err, rawData){
    //       var data2 = JSON.parse(rawData); reaches the servlet, however errors with the headers due to being the method for v4.

Comment: You need to read carefully what's written in Mike's comments to his code: *"you don’t need to check response.ok and call response.json"*; that's what `d3.json` is taking care of! If an error is encountered, whatsoever, the method will throw an exception which will lead to the Promise being rejected. This is not handled in your code.

Comment: Furthermore, there is a syntax error in your code which is subtle but important: your URL is defined as `"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/SomeServlet"` which is not what you want. Try to log it to console  to see the error. For the expression contained inside `${}` to be evaluated you need to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like Mike is doing in his original code. These literals have to be enclosed in backticks. Your code thus becomes ``d3.json(`${pageContext.request.contextPath}/SomeServlet` ``.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, have updated - also added in access-control-allow-methods/disabled browser cross origin restrictions with the same 405 `d3.select('#myButton').on('click', function(){
d3.json(`${pageContext.request.contextPath}/SomeServlet`, {
 method:"POST",
 body: JSON.stringify({"valuetosubmit": "test"}),
 headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',"content-type": "application/json"},
   mode: "cors"
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data); // [{"Hello": "world"}, …]
})
 
 });`

Comment: okay - im an idiot.. solved.. had to change my servlet from doget to dopost - appreciate the help above thanks